# error 403 in scrapy while crawling

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, data-extraction

Here is the code I have written to scrape the "blablacar" website.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class BlablaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blabla'

    allowed_domains = ['blablacar.in']
    start_urls = ['http://www.blablacar.in/ride-sharing/new-delhi/chandigarh']

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.text)
```

While running the above , iam getting error as

> 2018-06-11 00:07:05 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console
>   listening on 127.0.0.1:6023 2018-06-11 00:07:06 [scrapy.core.engine]
>   DEBUG: Crawled (403) http://www.blablacar.in/robots.txt>
>   (referer: None) 2018-06-11 00:07:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG:
>   Crawled (403) http://www.blablacar.in/ride-sharing/new-delhi/chandigarh> (referer:
>   None) 2018-06-11 00:07:06 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO:
>   Ignoring response <403
>   http://www.blablacar.in/ride-sharing/new-delhi/chandigarh>: HTTP
>   status code is not handled or not allowed 2018-06-11 00:07:06
>   [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

Answer (score 10):

You need to configure user agent. I run your code in my site with configured user agent and I got status code 200.

1 Put near by settings.py new file with name utils.py

```
import random

user_agent_list = [
    # Chrome
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36'
    # Firefox
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0'
]


def get_random_agent():
    return random.choice(user_agent_list)
```

2 Add to your settings.py file:

```
from <SCRAPY_PROJECT>.utils import get_random_agent

USER_AGENT = get_random_agent()
```

Answer (score 3):

[According to Scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror), you can use the handle_httpstatus_list spider attribute.

In your Case:

```
class BlablaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blabla'

    allowed_domains = ['blablacar.in']
    start_urls = ['http://www.blablacar.in/ride-sharing/new-delhi/chandigarh']
    handle_httpstatus_list = [403]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in html, a 403 error means that you do not have access to the page.

Try again with a different website if it doesn't show the same error then it's probably caused by the websites response